# Configure postfix to block PHP-sent mail() to certain recipients

Tags: php, postfix

I'm trying to prevent my CentOS 6.5 server from sending out emails to a certain list of recipients. (`dont_contact_me@hotmail.com`, `dont_contact_me@gmail.com` and so on).

I've configured postfix like this:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access
```

**/etc/postfix/recipient_access**:

```
dont_contact_me@hotmail.com REJECT
dont_contact_me@gmail.com REJECT
```

**DB is built via:**

```
postmap hash:recipient_access
```

**postfix is reloaded**

```
service postfix reload
```

**php.ini is:**

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seems to work. If i use PHP mail() to send a mail to `dont_contact_me@hotmail.com`, it is delivered as always.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I worked it out as I desired using virtual_alias_maps.

[I wrote about this here](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&u=http://turbolab.it/301&edit-text=) but basically you have to use `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/path/to/myblacklist.txt` and it will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

- It is because `smtpd_*_restrictions` only apply to the mails received by `smtpd` daemon through an `SMTP` transaction. The mails submitted using `sendmail` command is queued in `maildrop` queue by `postdrop` command, which is picked up by `pickup` and fed to `cleanup` directly.
- You can't restrict recipients for the mails submitted through `sendmail` command.

The only solution to this problem is force your applications to send mail only through `smtp` transaction.

Comment: That's it, thanks! Could you please give me a guide to configure PHP to go through smtp transaction? I need a server-wide, php.ini thing because I need to handle multiple, 3rd-party application running on the server.

Comment: Hope this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password

Comment: That is useful but not entirely correct: you can restrict access to the mail queue with authorized_submit_users. Consult the postdrop man to know more.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a alternative sendmail script like [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) to transport your `mail()` mails over smtp.
- After installing set `sendmail_path` in your php.ini file:

  ```
  sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/msmtp -C /etc/msmtprc -t -i
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to abuse `smtp_generic_maps` to divert this mail. Unlike the other directives you mentioned, this one operates on outgoing mail.

While it's not capable of dropping it, it can send it to a different mailbox, where you can then take appropriate action on it (such as suspending the customer who sent the mail).

In `main.cf` you would have:

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

And in `/etc/postfix/generic`:

```
banned_address@hotmail.com abuse@example.com
dont_contact_me@live.com abuse@example.com
```

This should send all such mail to your abuse mailbox for you to act on.

Comment: This is very interesting but unfortunately doesn't seems to work: this is my log with this in place http://pastebin.com/g1f3ZGU1 As you see, the mail still goes through.